# How to display an image from Ionic native image picker?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic native image picker: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/

I'm importing on my module

```
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';
```

And adding on the module's providers

```
ImagePicker,
```

On my page I'm importing it

```
import { ImagePicker, ImagePickerOptions } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';
```

Adding to my constructor

```
private imagePicker: ImagePicker,
```

Then calling a method on a button

```
async pickImageFromGallery() {
  try {
    const [imageSource] = await this.imagePicker.getPictures(this.pickerOptions);

    this.imgSrc = imageSource;
```

It does work and I can get the file URI, however when I try to display on an `<img>` tag the image doesn't show up

```
<img src="{{ imgSrc }}" alt="" />
```

Do I need to configure some permission or something? Why doesn't the image show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `this.imgSrc = imageSource;` I did

```
this.imgSrc = imageSource.replace('file://', '');
```

Works on both iOS and Android.

---

If you run into problems like Android crashing try this:

First I cleaned my project

```
# rm -rf
rimraf .sourcemaps node_modules platforms plugins www
```

Then installed packages

```
npm i
```

Then deploy the app again

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  "" in your src

```
<img src="{{ imgSrc }}" alt="" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot when writing the example, but my code has it

Comment: what is the value of this.imgSrc ?

Comment: On iOS it's `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../cdv_photo_000.jpg`