# How to display an image from Ionic native image picker with --livereload?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using this to display an image: [How to display an image from Ionic native image picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714500/how-to-display-an-image-from-ionic-native-image-picker)

It is working when I deploy to the device without `--livereload` flag. But when I'm using live reload the image does not show up. Happens on both Android and iOS.

Is there a way to fix it for live reload as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12714) with ionic-CLI. There is still no fix. You can use browsersync instead for your implementation.

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```